# How to send broadcast on a specific UDP port? (Getting error: `sendto failed: EINVAL`)

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, broadcast

*DISCLAMER:* I know there are already questions of the same topic, but the issue below is different from the other questions.

I'm trying to broadcast a packet on a certain port.

This does not work. My code: (I'm running this on my actual phone)

```
//Creating the socket (It's a class field, not a private element)
bcSock = new DatagramSocket(DEVICE_PORT, bcAddress);//bcAddress is explained below
bcSock.setBroadcast(true);
bcSock.setSoTimeout(LISTEN_TIMEOUT);
//Somewhere else in the code, creating the packet/sending it
 byte[] buf = PACKET_CONTENT.getBytes();
    DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, bcAddress, PORT);
    new SendUDPTask() {
        @Override
        public void handleException(Exception e) {
            //TODO Handle
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }.execute(bcSock, dp, LISTEN_TIMEOUT);
```

Where `SendUDPTask` is a public class that just does this: `sock.send(dp);`.

`bcAddress` is the default broadcast IP generated using this method:

```
public static InetAddress getBroadcastAddress(Activity activity) throws IOException {
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    DhcpInfo dhcp = wifi.getDhcpInfo();
    // handle null somehow

    int broadcast = (dhcp.ipAddress & dhcp.netmask) | ~dhcp.netmask;
    byte[] quads = new byte[4];
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        quads[k] = (byte) (broadcast >> (k * 8));
    return InetAddress.getByAddress(quads);
}
```

That way I get this error:

```
java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:542)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:511)
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:305)
    at me.nonamesldev.smarthouse.SendUDPTask.doInBackground(SendUDPTask.java:27)
    at me.nonamesldev.smarthouse.SendUDPTask.doInBackground(SendUDPTask.java:17)
```

(Line 27 is the `socket.send(packet)` part.)

Trying to create the Socket like so `DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(8888);` also doesn't work and thows a `NullPointerException` - `null buffer || null address` on `DatagramSocket.send`, even though the docs say this should be ok:

> `DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(null); s.bind(new InetSocketAddress(8888));` Which is equivalent to: `DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(8888);` Both cases will create a DatagramSocket able to receive broadcasts on UDP port 8888.

What do I do? I just want to broadcast on UDP on a certain port in Android. Why does it have to be so hard?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I've also tried creating the socket this way:

```
DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
DatagramSocket socket = channel.socket();
bcSock.bind(new InetSocketAddress(bcAddress, PORT));
```

Instead of `bcSock = new DatagramSocket(DEVICE_PORT, bcAddress);`, which produces the same error.

Comment: How many times are you going to delete and re-ask this question?

Comment: @EJP It's a different problem now, also my last question was wrongly closed and marked as a duplicate of an unrelated question. So, this is the second time. Please remove your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That worked for me:

### Sender

```java
bcSock = new DatagramSocket();
bcSock.setBroadcast(true);
byte[] buf = PACKET_CONTENT.getBytes();
DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, bcAddress, PORT);
bcSock.send(dp);
```

### Receiver

```java
DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(PORT);
byte[] buf = new byte[PACKET_CONTENT.getBytes().length];
DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
ds.receive(dp);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The combination of no address in the socket, setting the broadcast flag and putting the `bcAddress` in the packet is something I didn't think about :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not attempt to bind the socket to the broadcast address. Use INADDR_ANY, which in Java is an `InetAddress` of `null`.

Comment: Using a null `InetAddress` produces the following exception: `NullPointerException: Destination address is null`.

Comment: Using a null `InetAddress` in the `DatagramPacket` does that. I didn't mention any such thing. I am talking about the *socket.* Do read what is written here.